# Get expiring Azure AD applications

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get all the Azure AD Application secrets and certificates that will expire in the next 30 days. I'm using Get-AzADApplication piped to Get-AzADAppCredential to get the applications EndDate but it is not returning the correct results as it doesnt match the dates correctly even if I format them both exactly the same. The code below returns some apps that expire in 2025!

```
$todaysDate = (Get-Date -UFormat "%e/%m/%Y")
$expiryDate = Get-Date $(Get-Date).AddDays(30) -UFormat "%e/%m/%Y"

$aboutToExpire = Get-AzADApplication | ForEach-Object {
    $app = $_
    @(
      Get-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $_.ObjectId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    ) | Where-Object { (Get-Date $_.EndDate -UFormat "%e/%m/%Y") -le $expiryDate -and (Get-Date $_.EndDate -UFormat "%e/%m/%Y") -gt $todaysDate} | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            AppName = $app.DisplayName
            ObjectID = $app.ObjectId
            AppId = $app.ApplicationId
            StartDate = $_.StartDate
            EndDate = $_.EndDate
            ExpiryDate = $expiryDate
        }
    }
}
$aboutToExpire
```

Comment: Is this useful to you?  https://gist.github.com/svarukala/64ade1ca6f73a9d18236582e8770d1d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a date issue. The first issue was trying to parse the date. Thanks to @oleh-tarasenko for the parseexact code. The second issue was with the comparison operator trying to compare en-AU dates with en-US dates and either failing or outputting bad results. Trick was to provide the specific culture. Code below.

```
$CIDE = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
$endDate = [DateTime]::parseexact($secret.EndDate, "d/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", $CIDE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'm using for searching expired secrets and certs. I believe you have an issue with the date comparison because of the not correct date format, please take a look at my example.

```
$apps = Get-AzADApplication
$xs = Get-Date
$ys = Get-Date (Get-Date).AddDays(+60)
$alertListExps = @()
$alertListExpd = @()

foreach ($app in $apps) 
{ 
    $secrets = Get-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
    if ($null -eq $secrets){}
    else 
    {  
        foreach ($secret in $secrets) 
        { 
            $secretDate = [datetime]$secret.EndDate #::parseexact($secret.EndDate,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$null)
            
            if ($secretDate -le $xs) 
            {
               $alertListExpd += "*App:* " + $app.DisplayName + " *exired:* " + $secret.EndDate + ' ' + '(' + $secret.Type + ')' | Out-String
            }
            elseif ($secretDate -le $ys) 
            {
               $alertListExps += "*App:* " + $app.DisplayName + " *exires:* " + $secret.EndDate + ' ' + '(' + $secret.Type + ')' | Out-String
            }
        }
    }
```